# Is this there a defined behavior for this code that deletes a derived class through a base class pointer?

Tags: c++

Does this code result in defined behavior?

```
class A {
    int x;
};
class B {
    short y;
};
class C {
    double z;
};

class D : public A, public B, public C {
    float bouncy;
};

void deleteB(B *b) {
    delete b;
}

void is_it_defined() {
    D *d = new D;
    deleteB(d);

    B *b = new D;  // Is this any different?
    delete b;
}
```

If it's not defined, why not?  And if it is, what's it defined to do and why?  Lastly, if it's implementation defined, could you give an example of what a common implementation might define the behavior to be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does delete work with pointers to base class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294927/does-delete-work-with-pointers-to-base-class)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting [Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) :

> If deletion can be performed
>   polymorphically through the base class
>   interface, then it must behave
>   virtually and must be virtual. Indeed,
>   the language requires it - if you
>   delete polymorphically without a
>   virtual destructor, you summon the
>   dreaded specter of "undefined
>   behavior".

In your example, both `delete` are performed through base class pointers and yield undefined behavior. Standard 5.3.5 (Delete) :

> In the first alternative (delete
>   object), **if the static type of the
>   operand is different from its dynamic
>   type, the static type shall be a base
>   class of the operand’s dynamic type
>   and the static type shall have a
>   virtual destructor or the behavior is
>   undefined**.

Here, both `delete` act on static type `B` while the operand's dynamic type is `D`.

Comment: The problem here is that non of the classes is polymorphic. `B *b = new D;` stores the pointer of `B` inside the newly allocated `D`. And the delete will fail if `B` has a non-zero offset inside `D`. What the heck is undefined here?

Comment: Just note that in this example, the dynamic type of `b` is `B*` because `B` is not polymorphic.

Comment: @Let_Me-Be The dynamic type of b is D*.

Comment: Indeed, none of the clases is polymorphic. Yet, the code as it is written expects deletion to behave virtually.

Comment: @Sjoerd Yeah, and I guess you expect `typeid(*b)` to return `D`?

Comment: @icecrime Yes the code is wrong, there is no dispute in that. What we are talking about is if it is defined/undefined/implementation defined.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be No, I expect typeid(*b) == typeid(B), because class B has no virtual members. Typeid(*b) will not return the dynamic type in this case.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: the code as presented violates a "Shall" (5.3.5, the static type shall have a virtual destructor) and therefore has undefined behavior. There's no need for dispute or discussion. Similarly, Sjoerd is right on all other points.

Comment: @MSalters If the dynamic type is different from static type. I have already posted this into comp.std.c++ (waiting for response). I still claim that the dynamic and static type of `b` is `B*` because the `class B` is not polymorphic.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be *1.3.3 dynamic type : the type of the most derived object (1.8) to which the lvalue denoted by an lvalue expression refers*. Sorry, I don't see how the class being polymorphic has anything to do with it.

Comment: @icecrime Well, the `lvalue` doesn't refer to `D*` but `B*`, because in case of non-polymorphic classes there is no information about the `class D` preserved. This type is discarded in the assignment. You could say that even if there is no information about this, the compound memory block is still `D*`, well, what about placement new then? In that case, the compound block will be most likely `char*`. It's a wording issue, and that's why I asked for clarification in `comp.std.c++`.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be The fact that compilers don't record the information in case of non-polymorphic classes, doesn't matter at all. The C++ standard states that the dynamic type of b is D* (see the quotes digged up by icecrime), and that's all that counts.

Comment: @Sjoerd - I'm wondering what way of not being wrong our contrarian is going to find when the comp.std.c++ people tell h(im/er) that (s)he's wrong too.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

`B` doesn't have a **virtual** destructor, it should have.

Comment: Unless the classes are polymorphic, or contain dynamically allocated memory, destructors are irrelevant.

Comment: If there's any reason why we should be able to downvote comments, this would be it.

Answer (score -1):

is it all concern about the virtual destructor?
look at this:

```
class A 
{
    int x;

public:
    virtual void fun()
    {
        return;
    }
};

class D : public A 
{
    float bouncy;
};

void is_it_defined()
{

    A *b = new D;  // it`s ok!
    delete b;
}
```

u see? it`s ok. The pointer b can be delete correctly.
So, just need a vitual function to activate the polymorphic.

Comment: -1 for saying something that isn't correct.  You __do__ need a virtual destructor.  Not just any old virtual function.  I know you need a virtual destructor in this case, but my question isn't how to make it work properly.  My question is what happens when you don't do the right thing?  Is the result predictable in any way?

Comment: Of course, i need a virtual destructor to make resource be released correctly. But i have a question, why i add a virtual function, the delete operation is OK. I still confused by the object model. So i just post a question to discuss.

Comment: C++ doesn't work that way. It's a very powerful language, but that doesn't come for free. One of the downsides of C++ is that incorrect code may seem to work. Your code is a clear example. The code is wrong, but your compiler couldn't check at compile time and didn't bother to check at runtime. We know it's wrong because the standard specifically says it's wrong (see icecrime's response)